# Ng-repeat an array of images

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use an ng-repeat on an array of different images. Problem is, these images need to be in-line and do a flip transition. Here's what I had before I decided to use ng-repeat:

```
`<div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
           <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
               <div>
                   <div class="front">
                       <img id="firstTrophy" class="trophy locked" src="/img/trophy.png" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="back box">
                       <p class="text">
                     You're a champion!!!!
                       </p>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>`
```

And here's the ng-repeat I have now:

```
(in view.html)
`<div ng-repeat="trophy in trophies track by $index">
                          <img src="{{ trophy }}" />`
```

(in controller)

```
var trophies = [
"img/trophy.png",
"img/trophy.png",
"img/trophy.png",
"img/trophy.png",
"img/trophy.png"];
```

Thanks for any help you all can provide!

Comment: You should use `ng-src="{{trophy}}"` instead of `src`. Go through [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Answer (score 5):

Replace src with [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

```
<div ng-repeat="trophy in trophies track by $index">
                          <img ng-src="{{ trophy }}" />`
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/XPGXh/21/)**